# Will reissuing my credit card to get a new number every year or even more frequently hurt my credit or effective me negatively?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit

I recently had to have my card reissued because I noticed a charge on my account I did not make.

Then I realized I had this card for like 4 years and credit card numbers are static.

Why shouldn't I just reissue my card every year and get a new number? Would that hurt my credit in some way or have some negative impact.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't affect your Credit Score; but it also doesn't add any security:
Charges to the old number will automatically be 'forwarded' to the new number, *unless* you report fraud on the old number.
Even if you *do* (report fraud), regular payments will still be forwarded; only new ones will be declined. It is also not so easy to report fraud if none happened.

Comment: oh that's good to know, then that makes it totally pointless then. How long do they usually forward from an old number?

Comment: 30 to 45 days - so every monthly payment gets processed once.

Comment: You say "doesn't add any security" because of forwarding, but then say forwarding lasts at most 45 days. Wouldn't it add security past the 45 day mark then?

Comment: There is no usually.  I had an amex that continued to process a recurring payment until the expiration date.  Even though the stored number had been changed due to fraud, amex continued to process that payment on the old number until the recorded expiration date which was a couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

> Why shouldn't I just reissue my card every year and get a new number?

Because in four years you've only had to do that once, your way you would have had to do it four times.

> Would that hurt my credit in some way or have some negative impact.

No.  This wouldn't be a credit pull event.

Comment: what I mean is for security reasons would it make sense to get a new number every year?

Comment: I know what you mean.  All of the administration work that this event has required of you happened once in four years, call the credit card company, get the new card, change your stored numbers at amazon etc.  You're seeking to voluntarily add this administration more frequently.  Will you have less chance of a fraud event, maybe. Is it worth definitely replacing your card every year, I don't think so because you could still have fraudulent charges.  Just make sure you have a backup card.  In my wallet I carry one of my zero balance cards just as a backup to the one I actually use.

Answer (score -1):

To disagree with the other answers:
It did affect my credit score (in a very minor way). I applied for a credit card while making a purchase at a store ($30 savings). Card never arrived due to me moving. Now I have a closed account on my credit report and I have an open account.
If the credit report treats it as a new account the average age of your accounts will go down, which will pull down your credit score. Beyond that, though, everything stays the same so it shouldn't affect any other indicator of your credit score.

Comment: You applied for a credit card.  That's a completely different thing than what's being asked.  Reissuing a new card is not a new account it's not a credit report event.

Comment: I didn't say it was. Card had a balance, it had a number, it was reissued, it affected my credit.

Comment: ` I applied for a credit card`

Comment: Yes, I'm just going to restate what's already in the answer.... I applied for a credit card while making a purchase (thus the balance), it never arrived, thus I had a closed account on my credit, and I was issued a new card.

Comment: Which part of this do you think is relevant to the question at hand?  As I read this answer, it has absolutely nothing to do with the question.  Maybe you should expand if you think your reissue quirk that resulted in you having your whole account closed and second new account opened is the same as a person having a replacement card sent out.

Comment: The question was if you get a new card issued, will it affect your credit. My answer is that yes it does because that's what I did and I had a new account on the credit, and I now have a closed account on my credit. Thus it will affect your credit, mostly by lowering the average age of your accounts.

Comment: Your answer isn't about a new card issued.  It's about closing an account and opening a new one.  I've had, without exaggerating, 20 replacement cards sent to me it's never affected my account open date because a replacement card is not the same as a new account.

Comment: I guess your experience differs from mine, because I obviously didn't close the account and opened a new one.